# Updating ASP.Net / VB.Net database with strongly typed DataSet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset, tableadapter

We would like to update data in a SQL Server 2012 database with a value obtained from 
changing a value on an ASP.Net `DetailsView`. I Would would like to update the database using

- a strongly typed DataSet called `DataSetParentsDetails`
- a TableAdapter called `ParentsDetailsTableAdapter`
- a DataTable called `ParentsDetails`.

These were created with the DataSet Designer.

This is the code from the code-behind file used to figure out the amount we want to update into the database:

```
Protected Sub DetailsViewDetails_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewCommandEventArgs)
  Dim dcmAmountToAdjust As Decimal
  Dim StrSqlStatement As String

  Select Case e.CommandName
    Case "Add"
    Case "Edit"
      dcmOriginalRegistrationFee = GetValueFromLabelRegistrationFee()
    Case "Delete"
    Case "Update"
      dcmNewRegistrationFee = GetValueFromTextBoxRegistrationFee()
      dcmAmountToAdjust = dcmNewRegistrationFee - dcmOriginalRegistrationFee
      ' Update the tuition balance in the parent's data.
      '-------------------------------------------------
      StrSqlStatement =
        "Update Students " & _
        "Set RegistrationCode = RegistrationCode + @AmountToAdjust " & _
        "Where StudentID = @ID"
      ' Code to update the database goes here.
      '---------------------------------------
  End Select
End Sub
```

I'm sure that this was asked many times before but I can't find a good example on how to use the query in: `StrSqlStatement` to update the database through the strongly typed DataSet.

Comment: Am I missing the point here or would using a standard SqlConnection and SqlCommand not do the job? You can pass the parameters in and specify the data type, size, everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, if that's the easiest way to update the database. Please can you show a coding sample? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off you need a connection string, it's good practise to store your connection strings in the `web.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=putYourServerAndInstanceNameHere;Initial Catalog=putYourDatabaseNameHere;User ID=putYourSqlUsernameHere;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is a direct child of the root `<configuration>` element. For more information about connection strings, visit http://www.connectionstrings.com.

Then you'll need some imports in your code-behind, and you'll need to add them as references to your project if you haven't already got them in there:

```
Import System.Data
Import System.Data.SqlClient
```

Then we connect to the database and run our command, we use parameters because they're more secure.

```
'build the connection object using the string from the web.config file
Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ConnectionString)
  'build the command object specifying the command text and the connection to use, conn
  Using cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Students SET RegistrationCode = RegistrationCode + @AmountToAdjust WHERE StudentID = @ID", conn)
    'add the parameters needed by the command
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmountToAdjust", amountToAdjust)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", studentID)
    'try to open the connection and execute the statement
    Try
      conn.Open()
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
      'handle the exception here
    End Try
  End Using
End Using
```

Note that there is no need to use `conn.Close()` here as the `Using` statement will take care of that for you (SqlConnection's Dispose method closes the connection if it is still open).

Comment: Sean, you are so helpful! Thanks so much for the very detailed help. Everyone, please give this guy many "this answer is useful" up votes. :-)